# Download an excel file classic asp

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I'm trying to download an excel file (saved on the server) on a button click. When the event is raised it downloads a blank excel file instead of "WORK.xls"

```
 <%
     strFile = "WORK.xls"

     Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
     Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFile

     set app = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     app.open
     app.type = adTypeBinary
     app.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath("WORK.xls"))

    response.binarywrite app.Read

    app.close

   Set app = nothing

 %>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: a blank excel file is downloaded instead of the saved file on the server "WORK.xls"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DownloadFile "WORK.xls"

Private Sub DownloadFile(file)
    '--declare variables
    Dim strAbsFile
    Dim strFileExtension
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFile
    Dim objStream
    '-- set absolute file location
    strAbsFile = Server.MapPath(file)
    '-- create FSO object to check if file exists and get properties
    Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    '-- check to see if the file exists
    If objFSO.FileExists(strAbsFile) Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strAbsFile)
        '-- first clear the response, and then set the appropriate headers
        Response.Clear
        '-- the filename you give it will be the one that is shown
        ' to the users by default when they save
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & objFile.Name
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objFile.Size
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objStream.Open
        '-- set as binary
        objStream.Type = 1
        Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
        '-- load into the stream the file
        objStream.LoadFromFile(strAbsFile)
        '-- send the stream in the response
        Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read)
        objStream.Close
        Set objStream = Nothing
        Set objFile = Nothing
    Else 'objFSO.FileExists(strAbsFile)
        Response.Clear
        Response.Write("No such file exists.")
    End If
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Link: http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/08/downloading-any-file-using-asp-fso-and-the-adodb-stream-object/